# How to use nose coverage with --timid flag

Tags: python, nose, code-coverage

I'd like to run "nosetests --with-coverage" using [Ned Batchelder's coverage module](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/), but passing the coverage module the --timid flag.
Is there a way (e.g. setting an environment variable) to make coverage run with --timid?

Answer (score 3):

You've got two options:

1. Use a .coveragerc file to provide options to coverage.py
2. Instead of running coverage inside nose, run nose inside coverage:

   ```
   coverage run c:\python25\scripts\nosetests-script.py
   ```

(sorry for the Windows syntax if you aren't on Windows)

Comment: You can also set environment variable COVERAGE_OPTIONS to --timid