# Does coverage provide its own version of a nose plugin?

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose

The documentation for [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/cover.html) Version 1.3.7 says that

> Newer versions of coverage contain their own nose plugin which is superior to the builtin plugin. It exposes more of coverage’s options and uses coverage’s native html output. Depending on the version of coverage installed, the included plugin may override the nose builtin plugin, or be available under a different name. Check `nosetests --help` or `nosetests --plugins` to find out which coverage plugin is available on your system.

Running nosetests --plugins --verbose I can see that I have the plugin "coverage" with the description "Activate a coverage report using Ned Batchelder's coverage module."
For me it is not clear from this description what coverage plug-in I am using.

**With what version of coverage did the new nose plug-in become available?**

**How can I know if I am using it?**

**Does such a plug-in really exist?**

In May this year (2016) Ned Batchelder seems to advise the use of `coverage -m nose ...` and does not mention a new plug-in in their [issue-tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues/490/nosetests-with-coverage-seems-not-to-work) and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845626/5069869).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage has never provided its own nose plugin.

Notice that nose is no longer maintained, as the [nose documentation states](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> Nose has been in maintenance mode for the past several years and will likely cease without a new person/team to take over maintainership. New projects should consider using Nose2, py.test, or just plain unittest/unittest2.

If you must use nose, I continue to recommend using coverage to run nose:

```
coverage run -m nose ....
```